# Xcode4.3.2 AVFoundation.framework not found?

Tags: xcode4.3

Xcode4.3.2 AVFoundation.framework not found

I am missing the following Framework: /System/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework. so cannot use the AVFoundation frameworks for the iPhone simulator or device. Is there a way to download just this foundation?

can anyone help me please

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `you're missing it'? Isn't it in the SDK? Or you're just getting linker errors? (If the latter, try adding this framework...)

Comment: are you able to add this framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can see here
System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework
Refer this link too
[How add Framework to project on Xcode 4.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546374/how-add-framework-to-project-on-xcode-4-3-2)